# How do I store the $(TargetDir) in a variable

Tags: c#, macros, t4

I'm trying to store the Target Directory in a variable, However when I'm doing path.Combine it just ignores my parameters.

```
this._outputPath = "$(TargetDir)../../"
block.Name = "/Contracts/TestDTO";
var filePath = Path.Combine(this._outputPath, block.Name);
```

When I try this it ignores the output path probably because its not resolving properly.

As a Note this is being run from a T4 Generator meaning the application current directory is not the same as what I want.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"

Comment: You have to store the result of the combination somewhere, `Path.Combine` does not modify its arguments but returns a result.

Comment: sorry that was pseudo code I am storing it

Answer (score 0):

So It seems path.combine does not like to work with mixed slashes.

I fixed this by removing the / from the second path

```
this._outputPath = "$(TargetDir)../../"
block.Name = "Contracts/TestDTO";
var filePath = Path.Combine(this._outputPath, block.Name);
```